# IE9 Bug - Replaces innerHTML of anchor tag with href value. What are the causes of this?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

This is a shot in the dark whether or not anyone can help determine the source of this bug.

It was brought to my attention today that some JS in our web-app causes IE9 to replace the text-node content of an anchor tag, with the href attribute content. This completely breaks the styling of the top-level navigation. The curious thing, is that it only happens on one page in the application.

I've seen other answers to related questions and jQuery bug reports saying that IE9 does do this behavior when the href attribute is programmatically changed. The solution in those cases was to save the innerHTML before and after the change, and replace it with the original content. However, I don't think this is the cause of the problem.

This page is a Frankenstein of libraries; It includes GMaps API, Bootstrap.JS, Backbone.JS, Angular, Require.JS, IE polyfils, and a ton of proprietary stuff. I've tried in vain to figure out the source of this problem, and it would be good to know anything the codebase could be doing which would trigger this behaviour in IE.

Does anyone know of other factors which could cause IE to replace an `<a>` tag's innerHTML with the href value?

Comment: My guess is malformed HTML, but without more info, it's hard to tell.

Comment: I wish that were the case. The HTML seems to be fine, and the issue only presents itself on this particular page with its concoction of Javascript. All the other pages where the same nav bar is displayed, don't have the issue.